# How to resolve a syntax error of "unexpected token 'then'"?

Tags: bash, syntax, raspberry-pi, vpn

I'm trying to configure a VPN called ZeroTier to run on a Raspberry Pi. The Bash script I'm using for install is:

```
curl -s 'https://pgp.mit.edu/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x1657198823E52A61' | gpg --import && \ if z=$(curl -s 'https://install.zerotier.com/' | gpg); then echo "$z" | sudo bash; fi
```

Which gets me:

> -bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'then'

I've played around with the position of then and spaces between the `;` before and after the `)`, putting then against the semi colon, changing the to single quotes on `$z` and a few other things. I'm lost and don't understand why this script isn't working.

Comment: Remove backslash after `&&`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is due to the `\` present after `&&` in the script.

A backslash escapes the next character from being interpreted by the shell. If the next character is a newline, then the newline will not be interpreted as the end of the command by the shell. It effectively allows a command to span multiple lines. Also note that nothing (not even a comment or a single space) may follow the `\` on the lines that are broken up in this way.

For example, `ls; \ if true; then echo "Hi"; fi;`, will also produce the same error as yours but if you put the same in a script as below it won't produce the error.

```
ls; \
if true; then echo "Hi"; fi;
```

As below comment from **@glenn-jackman** pointed out, the reason bash has a problem with `then` is that there is no preceding `if`, instead there is a command named `"  if"`.

Additionally, you don't need `\` after `&&` in script. A newline is ignored in a few contexts where there is manifestly an unterminated command (`&&, ||, |, &, ;`). See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253518/where-are-bash-line-continuations-after-and-documented) for more.

Comment: The reason bash has a problem with `then` is that there is no preceding `if` -- instead there is a command named `" if"`

Comment: @glennjackman thank you both! I'm a complete noob but I love this community and appreciate the help and feedback.